# How to send a windows laptop automatically to sleep when no active screen is available?

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, sleep

My Windows laptop does not go into standby mode when I take it out of the docking station.

**Background**
I like to work with an external monitor and the laptop lid closed. Unfortunately, when I take the laptop out of the docking station, it does not go into standby mode, but drains the battery and heats up the case. I always have to manually put the laptop into standby mode before I put it away.

A friend of mine has already damaged his laptop screen (the glue turned yellow) because his laptop didn't go into standby mode and overheated in his bag....

**Configuration**
[image: Behavior when closing the lid]
To explain this setting: the laptop has to "do nothing"/keep running when I use the external monitor (which I currently only do when it is "plugged in"). When I work with my external monitor on battery power and close the lid, it goes into standby mode. As I only use an external monitor when I am also charging my laptop, this behavior is not perfect but acceptable. But it is really easy to forget to send the Laptop into stand before putting it into the case.

**Summary**.
Is it possible to automatically send the laptop into standby mode when the last monitor is unplugged (and the lid closed)?

Comment: Don't try to do something special, try to fix the problem that is occurring and get the system working normally. First, sleep issues are nearly always driver related, so start with that. Next, look up how to diagnose sleep problems. There are questions here about that already.

Comment: I don't think this is a driver issue. It's just a unwanted (but normal) behavior because Windows only triggers hibernation when the lid is closed and not when no screen is connected. But in most cases I also want my laptop to go into hibernation as soon as no screen is connected.